# Scroll whole window according to second frame in frameset

Tags: html, css, frameset

I have frameset with two frames.
First is a fixed height one and second can have different heights.

How could i implement solution that would scroll whole window
according to second frame, so the first frame would hide when someone
would scroll second frame down.

Code is a basic frame set

```
    <frameset rows="5%,95%">
       <frame src="/bar.html" scrolling=no >
       <frame name=myfr id="myframe" src="http://example.com">
    </frameset>
```

Comment: FYI - Frames and framesets are deprecated in HTML5, so you should consider another solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what frames and framesets are like, is there a reason you are using a frameset?